# Problem installing SharePoint 2010 Server Language Pack

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, language-pack

I'm trying to install Arabic Language Pack for SharePoint 2010 Server. The installation stops and show that an error occured while installing the pack but no detail on the error.

Where can I find log of the installation to get the detail of the error?

Thanx

Comment: check from this location C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Temp directory\

Comment: Thank you @waqas that was the right place. I found the logs, but the problem is more complex than I expected. Indeed I cleared the Windows Installer cache brutaly to free some space on my disk. But it seems that was a big mistake and now the most MSI packages installed on my system can't be updated, repaired or even uninstalled, and this affect the installation of the language pack :(

Comment: i add that as Answer, so that other get benefits and i will get credit. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the MSI installer Log files for more information.

To access the log files please go the below path.

```
C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Temp directory\
```